# ¿Cómo creo por consola un menú retornable?

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola buenas tardes coders.
Tengo un código que reliza lo siguiente:

- Creo un Array (Unidimensional) de 20 posiciones [0,19].
- Ejecuto un bucle que me va pregundando opciones
- - Dentro de este pregunto (mientras sea verdadero) escoger una opción (Switch-Case)
- - En la primera Introduzco en el Array un nombre
- - En la segunda "Supuestamente" listo alfabéticamente el Array ya mencionado
- - - En esta segunda creo una condición de que si el array está vacío o nulo que me muestre un error, si no muestra el valor del índice como el mismo índice.
- - En la 3era opción Salgo del programa
- - En la default doy salida de un mensaje de Error pero no lo paro, sigue preguntando opciones.

El problema viene a la hora de comprobar si el array está vacío (En el Case 2). Si el array lo declaro como nulo el primero no me funciona, si declaro el array con valor máximo 20 ([0,19]) no me funciona el segundo como debe (ya ni hablo de ordenarlo, al estar nulo tira error).
¿Qué es lo que tengo mal o por donde podría tirar? Alguna pista o algo, soy algo nuevo en JAVA asíque si me he saltado algo disculpad.

```
package claseTest;
// Importar Arrays
import java.util.Arrays;
// Importar Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test01{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Crear Variables Principales
        String Clientes[] = new String[20];
        int opcion, i = 0;
        // Inicializar scanner
        Scanner scInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scTxt = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Preguntar
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Escoja Opción: \t 1. Dar Alta Empleado \t 2. Listar Empleados \t 3. Comprobar Existencia Empleado \t 4. Salir del Programa");
            opcion = scInt.nextInt();
            // Switch Case
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    // Estética
                    System.out.println();
                    // Añadir Empleado
                    if(i < 20) {
                        System.out.println("Ha escogido la opción " + opcion + ". Introduzca el nombre del empleado -> " + i);
                        Clientes[i] = scTxt.nextLine(); 
                        System.out.println(Clientes[i]);
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("No se pueden añadir más clientes, lo sentimos.");
                    }
                break;
                case 2:
                    // Crear boolean
                    boolean hasValue = false;
                    // Estética
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Ha escogido la opción " + opcion + ". Se procederá a mostrar los Empleados.");
                    for(int j = 0; j <= Clientes.length; j++) {
                        if(Clientes[j] != null){
                            hasValue = true;
                            System.out.println("Cliente cuyo Nº es -> : " + j + " le corresponde el Nombre: " + Clientes[j]);
                        }else {
                            hasValue = false;
                        }
                    }
                    // Añadir Empleado
                    if(hasValue == false) {
                        // Estética
                        System.out.println();
                        // Output Error
                        System.out.println("No es posible, no se ha introducido ningún cliente.");
                    }
                    
                break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Ha escogido la opción " + opcion + ". Ha seleccionado salir del programa, hasta luego :-)");
                    System.exit(0);
                break;
                default:
                    // Estética
                    System.out.println();
                    // Error Output
                    System.out.println("Error, la opción " + opcion + " seleccionada no es válida.");
                break;
            }
            // Incrementar
            i++;
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en el rango del `for`:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= Clientes.length; j++)
```

Debe ser: `j < Clientes.length` [0 - 19].

---

Adicionalmente dentro del `for` solo debe ir la condición que haga que `hasValue` sea verdadero, ya que si existe al menos un elemento en el arreglo el arreglo no está vacío. Y si no hay ninguno será falso y ese valor ya se asignó al declarar la variable.

```
for(int j = 0; j < Clientes.length; j++) {
    if(Clientes[j] != null){
        hasValue = true;
        System.out.println("Cliente cuyo Nº es -> : " + j + " le corresponde el Nombre: " + Clientes[j]);
    }
}
```

---

Algunas sugerencias:

No se necesitan dos objetos de Scanner, con uno es suficiente.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

No comparar las expresiones booleanas con false, en lugar de eso usar el operador de negación `!`.

```
if(!hasValue) {
   
}
```

**Actualización**

Para evitar los errores de `NullPointerException` se puede inicializar el arreglo `Clientes` con cadenas vacías:

```
// Crear Variables Principales
String Clientes[] = new String[20];

{
    // llenar el arreglo con cadenas vacías
    Arrays.fill(Clientes,"");
}
```

Y para saber si está vacío usar el método `isEmpty()` de la cadena:

```
if(!Clientes[j].isEmpty()){
    hasValue = true;
    System.out.println("Cliente cuyo Nº es -> : " + j + " le corresponde el Nombre: " + Clientes[j]);
}
```

Ahora como el arreglo ya no tiene valores `null` se pude usar `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: Hola! Esos 2 Scanner lo hago porque como mezclo int y String (lo tengo demostrado) el propio hilo de ejecución o algo dentro del Scanner da fallo y no funciona como debe ser, por eso puse 2 para diferenciar los  números de los textos. Un saludo, voy a probar si funciona y te comento.

Comment: Hola buenas de nuevo, me funciona correctamente como dices, pero cómo lo ordenaría en este caso, podría seguir tirando de Arrays.sort() o tendría que utilizar un bucle para la ordenación. Gracias y un saludo de antemano

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta para dejar de trabajar con valores `null` y poder usar `Arrays.sort()`.

Comment: Estupendo, también estuve googleando un poco y encontré esto:
     Arrays.sort(Clientes,Comparator.nullsLast(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));

Me lo hace también como tu me dices pero con null. En este caso tengo que trabajar con null (me lo piden explícitamente). Muchas gracias por la ayuda !